# Rails collection route to delete many records at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I created a collection route for remove_multiple:

```
resources :myfiles do
  collection do
    delete 'remove_multiple' => 'myfiles#remove_multiple'
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<%= form_tag remove_multiple_myfiles_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
.....
<td><%= check_box_tag "myfile_ids[]", myfile.id %></td>
.....
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Delete all" %>
<% end %>
```

And here's my controller:

`before_action :set_myfile, :check_user, except: [:remove_multiple]`

```
def remove_multiple
 @myfiles = Myfile.find(params[:myfile_ids])
 @myfiles.each do |myfile|
  myfile.destroy
 end
 flash[:notice] = "Deleted files!"
 redirect_to trashcan_path
end
```

But here's what the console says:

```
Started DELETE "/myfiles/remove_multiple" for ::1 at 2015-01-20     14:16:02 +0530
Processing by MyfilesController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VebaegOfVddyLiOs9oWP4DcLReC7ZPyttpKulIWMOMZN1JJ18T07aMirTSsqWkiDZOL8yMZ1iYi093tk4Qx4KQ==", "myfile_ids"=>["55", "56", "57"], "commit"=>"Delete all", "id"=>"remove_multiple"}
Myfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `myfiles`.* FROM `myfiles` WHERE `myfiles`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :set_myfile rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Why is it executing Myfiles#destroy method? Even when I specify the route?

Comment: whats in your set_myfile method?

Comment: It was created my the scaffold. It's the standard: 

def set_myfile
      @myfile = Myfile.find(params[:id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to(root_path)
    end

Comment: You're not passing id to params[:id], therefore you dont even get into your delete method

Comment: It's not supposed to go to destroy action. It's supposed to go to remove_multiple, which never needs to hit the set_myfile or needs an ID. Since it's a collection route.

Comment: @SwaathiK, In your view, in the form do you have a single my_file object or an array. from your controller it looks like you are trying remove all my_files associated with the product. But from view it looks like you are trying to delete a single my_file. Please clarify :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Let me recheck.

Answer (score 2):

In your routes.rb :

```
resources :myfiles do
  collection do
    delete 'remove_multiple'
  end
end
```

# In your View.

```
 # You are not passing the object id which you want to delete. 
 # see here, we are passing my_file.id in the path 
    <%= form_tag remove_multiple_myfiles_path(file_id: my_file.id), 
       method: :delete do %>
    <% end %>
```

#my_files_controller.rb

```
#Exclude your remove_multiple action from any before_actions.
   def remove_multiple
     file_ids = params["myfile_ids"]
      Product.where(id: file_ids).destroy_all
   end
```

Comment: I am passing the ID's via the checkbox. If you check the log I posted above you'll see that the ID's are infact being passed, but just to the wrong controller action.

Comment: Great then if params are coming then the issue must be with route redirection try adding routes the  way I have shown in this answer. 

By the way, you are getting multiple file_ids 
Product.delete_all(["id in (?)", params['myfile_ids'] ])

Comment: Just change the route as I specified the try to get the params in the remove_multiple action(you can inspect by using raise params.inspect ) 
 Then use Product.where(id: params['myfile_ids']).destroy_all 
Try and let me know if that does not work. :)

Comment: The routes are the same exact way. I have just added a further controller action to map to the route. The issue is it is redirecting to the wrong controller function. It's not an issue with params :)

Comment: Yes, here the concern is only with the routes & hitting the incorrect action. After that you can handle the params. Notice: delete 'remove_multiple' => 'myfiles#remove_multiple', instead just mention delete 'remove_multiple' 

I have created a sample app, and it works for me. :)

Comment: Unfortunately. that was not the issue. The routes are still not hitting the correct action. It is not a problem with the params.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69199/discussion-between-ajay-and-swaathi-k).

Comment: Try running rake routes | grep 'myfiles' in your terminal , that you can show you the correct redirections. 2nd case, may be any of your before_actions in my_files_controller or applications_controller causing the trouble.

Comment: Yeah it is the before action causing redirect. Because it is calling the destroy action. Please read through the question before providing help. I am repeating the same things other wise.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
resources :myfiles do
    collection do
        delete "/" => :remove_multiple, as: :remove_multiple 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Rails 4 right? It looks fine, but `delete :remove_multiple` should be clearer than `delete 'remove_multiple' => 'myfiles#remove_multiple'`. Run `rake routes` first, see what `remove_multiple_myfiles_path` is mapped to.

Comment: It's mapped to the proper controller function. `remove_multiple_myfiles DELETE /myfiles/remove_multiple(.:format)              myfiles#remove_multiple`. But I have no idea where this weird behavior is coming from.

Comment: Yeah it's weird. Both your route and form looks legit. If I were you, I'd run `curl -X DELETE http://host:post/myfiles/remove_multiple` first(you need to add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to disable csrf protection for now). If it's processed by the right action, then the problem is in you form, if not, then it's something wrong with the route. If still nothing comes up, see what's in you Gemfile. And what's your Rails version anyway, I checked with 4.0.2, it worked as expected.

Comment: I changed the HTTP method to POST and it immediately started working. What's up with that? :/

Comment: Sorry can't reproduce on either Rails 4.0 or Rails 4.1. Maybe you should test with a simple example. Create a new controller, add the route, test it with curl to see if it works first.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with routes. I don't know if this is specific to my Rails app or to Rails itself, but the routes are not allowing for a DELETE method in collection, instead it keeps redirecting to the default destroy action.

So I just made my remove_multiple route as POST.

```
collection do
  post 'remove_multiple' => 'myfiles#remove_multiple'
end
```